# Php admin panel generator

Tags: php, admin, crud

Is there any library that, given a sqlite/mysql/postgres database generates an admin panel to manage data *à la* Django? I know that some frameworks do this, but I need something indipendent from any other part of the application that relies solely on a given database to work.

I need something end-user oriented, so any sql-based tool (like phpMyAdmin) would not work. Thanks

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of suggestions for use with mysql:

http://www.ajaxcrud.com creates an ajax crud interface.  The main page provides a good example with code, and there are more advanced examples on the site as well.

There is also http://www.phpscaffold.com/ which you can use to create some skeleton pages if you prefer to have more control.

I have used both of these previously in projects and they work well.

Comment: Just found this which looks useful http://www.aaronharp.com/dev/php-scaffold-class/

Answer (score 2):

You can check [PHP Admin Panel](http://www.phpadminpanel.com).

It's not free but it's not expensive for what you can do.

Comment: now it's www.phpadminpanel.com

Answer (score 1):

How about [Adminer Editor](http://adminer.org/editor/)? It's pretty cool.